# JQuery: Changing JQuery Selector Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML `div` that are assigned with different `id` attribute using `EJS`. It looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="<%= posts._id %>"></div>
```

This `div` is generated several times in the HTML depending on how many posts a particular user has. Each of the `div` has a different `posts._id`.

I would like that when a user click on a `div`, JQuery will do something with that particular `div` only. Other `div` should not be changed. How can I change the JQuery selector based on the `id` attribute of a particular `div`?

**JQuery**

```
$("//How to change this part based on the `div`'s id?").click(function(){
    //action taken
});
```

Comment: Sorry for asking this. Is <%= posts._id %> processed on the server side or is the html rendered like that?

Comment: It's rendered server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS class  to the element

```
<div id="<%= posts._id %>" class="posts"></div>
```

Then event handlers can be attached using Class selector

```
$(".posts").click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
});
```

---

I would recommend you to use custom `data-*` attribute to persist arbitrary data i.e. *postId* which can be retried using `data(key)`

```js
$(".posts").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="100" class="posts">Click</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering, what happen if some of the other HTML elements have the same `id` as the clicked `div`? Does the `this.id` refer particularly to the clicked `div`?

Comment: @Steven, I'd must be unique in the HTML document and this.id refer to id of the div clicked

Answer (score 0):

That's what `classes` are for.

Give a common `class` to all of your divs, and use this `class` to select them in Javascript :

**HTML**

```
<div id="<%= posts._id %>" class="common-class"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".common-class").click(function(){
    //action taken
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

HTML

`<div id="post_<%= posts._id %>"></div>`

JS
Find all [starting with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `post_`

`$("div[id^='post_']").click(function() { ... })`